# Import CSV Using Mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

Currently I need to push a large CSV file into a mongo DB and the order of the values needs to determine the key for the DB entry:

Example CSV file:

```
9,1557,358,286,Mutantville,4368,2358026,,M,0,0,0,1,0
9,1557,359,147,Wroogny,4853,2356061,,D,0,0,0,1,0
```

Code to parse it into arrays:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var csv = require("fast-csv");

fs.createReadStream("rank.txt")
    .pipe(csv())
    .on("data", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
    .on("end", function(data){
        console.log("Read Finished");
    });
```

Code Output:

```
[ '9',
  '1557',
  '358',
  '286',
  'Mutantville',
  '4368',
  '2358026',
  '',
  'M',
  '0',
  '0',
  '0',
  '1',
  '0' ]
[ '9',
  '1557',
  '359',
  '147',
  'Wroogny',
  '4853',
  '2356061',
  '',
  'D',
  '0',
  '0',
  '0',
  '1',
  '0' ]
```

How do I insert the arrays into my mongoose schema to go into mongo db?

Schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");


var rankSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   serverid: Number,
   resetid: Number,
   rank: Number,
   number: Number,
   name: String,
   land: Number,
   networth: Number,
   tag: String,
   gov: String,
   gdi: Number,
   protection: Number,
   vacation: Number,
   alive: Number,
   deleted: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Rank", rankSchema);
```

The order of the array needs to match the order of the schema for instance in the array the first number 9 needs to always be saved as they key "serverid" and so forth.  I'm using Node.JS

Comment: You cannot insert an "array", and you need to convert it to an "object". Usually you would know what the fields should be, either as predefined or by a headerline within the CSV itself. Most CSV parsers will in fact support that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with fast-csv by getting the [`headers`](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv#data-types) from the schema definition which will return the parsed lines as "objects". You actually have some mismatches, so I've marked them with corrections:

```
const fs = require('mz/fs');
const csv = require('fast-csv');

const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const rankSchema = new Schema({
  serverid: Number,
  resetid: Number,
  rank: Number,
  name: String,
  land: String,         // <-- You have this as Number but it's a string
  networth: Number,
  tag: String,
  stuff: String,        // the empty field in the csv
  gov: String,
  gdi: Number,
  protection: Number,
  vacation: Number,
  alive: Number,
  deleted: Number
});

const Rank = mongoose.model('Rank', rankSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri);

    await Promise.all(Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove()));

    let headers = Object.keys(Rank.schema.paths)
      .filter(k => ['_id','__v'].indexOf(k) === -1);

    console.log(headers);

    await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

      let buffer = [],
          counter = 0;

      let stream = fs.createReadStream('input.csv')
        .pipe(csv({ headers }))
        .on("error", reject)
        .on("data", async doc => {
          stream.pause();
          buffer.push(doc);
          counter++;
          log(doc);
          try {
            if ( counter > 10000 ) {
              await Rank.insertMany(buffer);
              buffer = [];
              counter = 0;
            }
          } catch(e) {
            stream.destroy(e);
          }

          stream.resume();

        })
        .on("end", async () => {
          try {
            if ( counter > 0 ) {
              await Rank.insertMany(buffer);
              buffer = [];
              counter = 0;
              resolve();
            }
          } catch(e) {
            stream.destroy(e);
          }
        });

    });


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }


})()
```

As long as the schema actually lines up to the provided CSV then it's okay. These are the corrections that I can see but if you need the actual field names aligned differently then you need to adjust. But there was basically a `Number` in the position where there is a `String` and essentially an extra field, which I'm presuming is the blank one in the CSV.

The general things are getting the array of field names from the schema and passing that into the options when making the csv parser instance:

```
let headers = Object.keys(Rank.schema.paths)
  .filter(k => ['_id','__v'].indexOf(k) === -1);

let stream = fs.createReadStream('input.csv')
  .pipe(csv({ headers }))
```

Once you actually do that then you get an "Object" back instead of an array:

```
{
  "serverid": "9",
  "resetid": "1557",
  "rank": "358",
  "name": "286",
  "land": "Mutantville",
  "networth": "4368",
  "tag": "2358026",
  "stuff": "",
  "gov": "M",
  "gdi": "0",
  "protection": "0",
  "vacation": "0",
  "alive": "1",
  "deleted": "0"
}
```

Don't worry about the "types" because Mongoose will cast the values according to schema.

The rest happens within the handler for the `data` event. For maximum efficiency we are using [`insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#insertmany_insertMany) to only write to the database once every 10,000 lines. How that actually goes to the server and processes depends on the MongoDB version, but 10,000 should be pretty reasonable based on the average number of fields you would import for a single collection in terms of the "trade-off" for memory usage and writing a reasonable network request. Make the number smaller if necessary.

The important parts are to mark these calls as `async` functions and `await` the result of the [`insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#insertmany_insertMany) before continuing. Also we need to [`pause()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) the stream and [`resume()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume) on each item otherwise we run the risk of overwriting the `buffer` of documents to insert before they are actually sent. The [`pause()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) and [`resume()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume) are necessary to put "back-pressure" on the pipe, otherwise items just keep "coming out" and firing the `data` event.

Naturally the control for the 10,000 entries requires we check that both on each iteration and on stream completion in order to empty the buffer and send any remaining documents to the server.

That's really what you want to do, as you certainly don't want to fire off an async request to the server both on "every" iteration through the `data` event or essentially without waiting for each request to complete. You'll get away with not checking that for "very small files", but for any real world load you're certain to exceed the call stack due to "in flight" async calls which have not yet completed.

---

FYI - a `package.json` used. The [`mz`](https://github.com/normalize/mz) is optional as it's just a modernized `Promise` enabled library of standard node "built-in" libraries that I'm simply used to using. The code is of course completely interchangeable with the `fs` module.

```
{
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "fast-csv": "^2.4.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.1",
    "mz": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

---

Actually with Node v8.9.x and above then we can even make this much simpler with an implementation of `AsyncIterator` through the [`stream-to-iterator`](https://github.com/seangenabe/stream-to-iterator) module. It's still in `Iterator<Promise<T>>` mode, but it should do until Node v10.x becomes stable LTS:

```
const fs = require('mz/fs');
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const streamToIterator = require('stream-to-iterator');

const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const rankSchema = new Schema({
  serverid: Number,
  resetid: Number,
  rank: Number,
  name: String,
  land: String,
  networth: Number,
  tag: String,
  stuff: String,        // the empty field
  gov: String,
  gdi: Number,
  protection: Number,
  vacation: Number,
  alive: Number,
  deleted: Number
});

const Rank = mongoose.model('Rank', rankSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri);

    await Promise.all(Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove()));

    let headers = Object.keys(Rank.schema.paths)
      .filter(k => ['_id','__v'].indexOf(k) === -1);

    //console.log(headers);

    let stream = fs.createReadStream('input.csv')
      .pipe(csv({ headers }));

    const iterator = await streamToIterator(stream).init();

    let buffer = [],
        counter = 0;

    for ( let docPromise of iterator ) {
      let doc = await docPromise;
      buffer.push(doc);
      counter++;

      if ( counter > 10000 ) {
        await Rank.insertMany(buffer);
        buffer = [];
        counter = 0;
      }
    }

    if ( counter > 0 ) {
      await Rank.insertMany(buffer);
      buffer = [];
      counter = 0;
    }

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }

})()
```

Basically, all of the stream "event" handling and pausing and resuming gets replaced by a simple `for` loop:

```
const iterator = await streamToIterator(stream).init();

for ( let docPromise of iterator ) {
  let doc = await docPromise;
  // ... The things in the loop
}
```

Easy! This gets cleaned up in later node implementation with `for..await..of` when it becomes more stable. But the above runs fine on the from the specified version and above.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for that!  I do have another question about the fs.createReadStream('input.csv').  Is it possible for that command to get the file from a web URL instead of a local file on my server?

Comment: @Ryansworld84 Not from a `fs` command since that means "file system" of which a remote URI is not. There is `request` which can do that, and returns a stream when asked for. If you have further questions then please [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: One last question, when this runs it does clear out the DB and reloads everything, is there a way to make it append more on instead of clearing it out then loading the csv?  So for example if it loads 10 lines from the CSV, then it runs 10 mintues later again and loads another 10 lines from the CSV can it just add them to the DB and not delete the orginal 10 and have 20 entrys?

Comment: @Ryansworld84 It's an "example" and not meant to be "ready to use code" for you. Simply don't call the `remove()`. I'm just doing this so you can run the "example" over and over in order to understand it.

Comment: Wrote a nodejs script with a csv file of 4500 rows, the stream-to-iterator solution hung, the 1st solution worked though. Thanks a bunch @NeilLunn

Answer (score 0):

By saying @Neil Lunn need **headerline** within the CSV itself.

Example using **csvtojson** module.

```
const csv = require('csvtojson');

const csvArray = [];
  csv()
    .fromFile(file-path)
    .on('json', (jsonObj) => {
      csvArray.push({ name: jsonObj.name, id: jsonObj.id });
    })
    .on('done', (error) => {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error});
      }
          Model.create(csvArray)
      .then((result) => {
         return res.status(200).json({result});
      }).catch((err) => {
          return res.status(500).json({ error});
      });
      });
    });
```