# Mongoose Model.create() function doesn't save all values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save an array of documents to a MongoDb Atlas Cloud cluster but not all the documents are being saved. The array has 14000 documents with the schema for the documents shown below. I am currently on the free MongoDb Atlas cluster so my first guess is that it doesn't have the processing power necessary to save all the documents before timing out?

Neither console.log in the .then or the .catch is being triggered on the .create call. I have removed the collection from mongo and ran it again with varying counts of documents saved.

```
//The schema file 

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const IngredientsSchema = new Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  term: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  searchValue: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const Ingredients = mongoose.model('Ingredients', IngredientsSchema, 'Ingredients');

module.exports = Ingredients;

//From the controller making the db call

Ingredients.create(arrayOfDocs)
    .then(dbArr => {
        console.log(`ingredients metadata added to database`)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

This is my first project using mongodb as well as the Mongo Atlas service. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anywhere from 4000-8000 are being saved. I am calling mongoose.connect in a config file elsewhere

Comment: For 1000's, calling `create()` is a bad idea. It actually interprets as **separate** `insertOne()` statements to MongoDB. It's often best to use `insertMany()`, and even then it's generally best to send "batches" rather than a *huge* array you effectively have loaded in memory. The "trade off" is `create()` actually applies other schema hooks and rules that might be applied, where as `insertMany()` will not. However such a *bulk insertion* really should have vetted the data and not need such validation checks.

Comment: In short, your 14000 comes from somewhere external obviously. So instead of reading in everything and trying to insert in one operation, just read in "chunks", process it and then send it on for insertion and repeat the process. Your application will consume far less memory and with a bit more *tweaking* you can even get parallel inserts, which would be much faster. Also another difference is `create()` will insert everything that does not violate a duplicate key. Using `insertMany()` you would need `ordered: false` to get the same effect. But insertion order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Though it's not really clear in your question where your 14,000 documents are actually coming from, you might want to look at: [Import CSV Using Mongoose Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343116/import-csv-using-mongoose-schema/50344607#50344607) which shows a *"reasonably modern"* example of loading data from a CSV file as a "stream" and then inserting "batches" to MongoDB. Also matches up the CSV content to the defined schema on the model, for what that's worth.